# Drawing app android: how to undo path, fill color

Tags: android, drawing, paint, undo

I'm creating drawing app with feature undo.My app can draw line, fill color.
If my app just have a feature draw line, I  have solution use array list store path and redraw when use tap undo
But now my app support fill color (paint bucket) feature. I don't found best solution to undo.
Does anyone have ideas??????

Answer (score 0):

For undo and redo

```
 public void onClickUndo () { 
 if (paths.size()>0) { 
   undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1))
   invalidate();
 }
 else
 //toast the user 
}

public void onClickRedo (){
if (undonePaths.size()>0) { 
   paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1)) 
   invalidate();
} 
else 
 //toast the user 
}
```